# Show More Less With Vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to accomplish a task where, I have 12 items aligned as 4 items per column, initially the first four items are visible others are hidden until we click the button "show more " one row of four cols appears , and then again pressing the button the other 4 items are visible . Then we have less button on click of which the second and third row is hidden and only the first is visible.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      limitationList: 5,
      products: {
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "2",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "3",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "4",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "5",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "6",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "7",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "8",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "9",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "10",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "11",
          price: "82.75"
        },
        {
          name: "a",
          category: "12",
          price: "82.75"
        },
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateLimitation(limitationList) {
      if (this.limitationList == this.product.length) {
        this.limitationList = 5
      } else {
        this.limitationList = this.product.length
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>

        <v-container>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 md3 lg3 xl3 mb-3 v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" v-if="product && product.length > 0 && index <= limitationList">
              <div class="pa-4">
                <div class="pt-3">
                  <p class="mb-0">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{product.category}}</a>
                  </p>
                  <h5><a href="javascript:void(0)"> {{product.name}}</a></h5>
                  <div fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                    <p class="accent-color">
                      {{product.price}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you thought about iterating over a computed result array that uses `.slice()` and a `page` -type variable to compute how many items to show

Comment: Not familiar with that ..I'm new to javascript have no knowledge about it

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short description of what I wrote out in my comment.

the basic mechanism is the "computed" section, which updates the changes made to the corresponding variables (rough description). You can get a better description by looking [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    products: [
       {
          name: "a",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "b",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "c",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "d",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "e",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "f",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "g",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "h",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "i",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "j",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "k",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "l",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "m",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "n",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "o",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
         {
          name: "p",
          category: "a",
          price: "82.75"
        },
    ],
    currentPage: 1,
  },
  computed:{
    toBeShown() {
        return this.products.slice(0, this.currentPage * 4);
    },
    totalPages() {
        return Math.ceil( this.products.length / 4);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage(){
        if(this.currentPage <  this.totalPages) this.currentPage++;
    },
    prevPage(){
        this.currentPage = this.currentPage - 1 || 1;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body{
  padding:5px;
}
.row{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.row .col{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  flex:0 0 calc(25% - 4px);
  border:1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 0 1px;
  padding:8px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Products</h3>
    <div>
      <button @click="prevPage" :disabled="currentPage==1">Show Less</button>
      <button @click="nextPage" :disabled="currentPage == totalPages">Show More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" v-for="(product,pIndex) in toBeShown" :key="pIndex">
      <h3>{{product.name}} <small>{{product.category}}</small></h3>
      <p>${{product.price}}</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you change the `:disable` to `v-if` and for the "show less" button, something like `currentPage != 1` should work, and for the second one `currentPage != totalPages`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Jhecht, using `slice` and grouping your items into columns will allow you to achieve this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      visible: 1
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    const max = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + 20

    this.items = Array.from(Array(max), (x, i) => `Item ${i + 1}`)
  },
  computed: {
    columns() {
      let columns = []
      for (i = 0; i < this.visible; i++) {
        columns.push(this.items.slice(i * 4, (i * 4) + 4))
      }
      return columns
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: .25rem;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container > div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: .25rem;
  margin: .25rem;
}

#container > div > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: .25rem;
  padding: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="visible = visible > 1 ? visible - 1 : visible" :disabled="visible < 2">Less</button>
  <button @click="visible = visible * 4 >= items.length ? visible : visible + 1" :disabled="visible * 4 >= items.length">More</button>
  <div id="container">
  <div v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index">
      <div v-for="item in column" :key="item">{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a "show more" Vue 3 component that works by displaying a page of children DOM elements, and allowing the user to click 'show more' to reveal another page:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, useSlots, watch } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    perPage: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
});

const slots = useSlots();

const amountToShow = ref(props.perPage);
const totalChildrenCount = computed(() => slots.default()[0].children.length);
const childrenToShow = computed(() => slots.default()[0].children.slice(0, amountToShow.value));
const isShowingShowMore = computed(() => {
    if (amountToShow.value === totalChildrenCount.value) return false;
    if (totalChildrenCount.value <= props.perPage) return false;
    return true;
});

watch(() => props.perPage, () => {
    amountToShow.value = props.perPage;
});

const showMore = () => {
    const nextAmount = (amountToShow.value + props.perPage);
    if (nextAmount > totalChildrenCount.value) {
        amountToShow.value = totalChildrenCount.value;
    } else {
        amountToShow.value += props.perPage;
    }

};
</script>

<template>
    <component
        :is="child"
        v-for="(child, index) in childrenToShow"
        :key="`show-more-${child.key}-${index}`"
    ></component>

    <button
        v-if="isShowingShowMore"
        class="w-full bg-grey-50 text-primary rounded-md p-2 mt-2"
        @click="showMore"
    >
        Show More
    </button>
</template>

<style>
    .w-full {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .bg-grey-50 {
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    .text-primary {
        color: blue;
    }
    .rounded-md {
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .p-2 {
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .mt-2 {
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
</style>
```

Usage

```
<ShowMore :per-page="5">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="`item-${index}`">
        Test
    </div>
</ShowMore>
```

You could accomplish a "show less" button by making a `showLess` function that calls

```
amountToShow.value -= props.perPage;
```